# Gender in USA Childcare vs UK

Tags: usa, children

Context: I am male, 22 years old, and engaged to a lady from Colorado, USA. I have volunteered and worked in playgroups and preschool settings in the UK, and when I am in the US (currently applying for the K-1 visa), I wish to continue working in preschool settings (possibly nannying but most likely preschools).

(My understanding is that I will need an AAS degree up to pre-K, or a masters for Kingergarden+.)

So my question is this.

*How will my experience working with children **as a (young) man** differ in the USA as opposed to the UK?*

(My experience of discomfort/discrimination in the UK is primarily suspicious looks, the ladies I've worked with have all been fine with it or enthusiastic to have a man for the children)

Will there be more resistance/discomfort with a man? From staff? Parents?

Would that be more implicit or explicit?

Would I be protected by any discrimination laws differently from the UK?

Does anyone have experience with their own children in the USA?

Comment: You might ask or migrate this question to [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com).

Comment: There's a case for parenting (asking parents who they'd want teaching their own children that its) or even workplace, but as I'm asking specifically for a comparison of the two, I went for expats. Still if anyone thinks it Should be elsewhere, do please move it, or demand I do. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

I am going to throw out some commentary, but I wouldn't consider this a complete answer.

You would be covered under sex (gender) discrimination laws which include race, national origin, religion, citizenship. These and more are considered ["protected classes."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_class)

There's a very heightened awareness about child abuse in the US. At a kid's camp that my company runs during our huge conference, they always tried to have both female and male counselors/teachers in order to accompany children to the bathrooms. The kids were not allowed to go on their own because they were publicly accessible. Because of that, I would get a police report/clearance or the equivalent from the UK that you can provide to prospective employers. Or pay for a background check in the UK from a company that will be willing to send the report directly to requestors.

For any job involving children, you will likely have to have a US background check run and this may help.

I don't have the details on educational requirements, but for public schools (government-run/funded), you need to be certified. Here's the [main page](https://www.cde.state.co.us/cdeprof) for Colorado. Based on a quick look that requires the equivalent of Bachelor's degree. Sometimes school districts will hire uncertified teachers, particularly for a shortage area like science or math, but it's frowned upon, and the teachers are strongly encouraged to become certified as quickly as possible.

Many teachers do get a master's or Ph.D later, but an advanced degree is not required for initial certification. An advanced degree will increase your pay, and if you want to move into administration (principal), it's almost required.

I would be thrilled if there were a male teacher at the day care my kids go to. One of my boys seems to prefer men, although he loves his female teachers. But, yes, you're sure to get some, "really?" comments. It'll likely be implicit, or indirect from parents or other teachers. I think some parents will be more likely to complain to the owner/manager/head teacher that they'd rather prefer a woman for their kid.

You may also run into dismissive or derogatory comments from other men. Not so much if you're teaching post-kindergarten/elementary school, but more likely if you say you're working at a preschool or day care.